# Recorrer array y guardar los elementos que cumplen una condición

Tags: java

Estoy recorriendo un array de String con un bucle `for` poniendo una condición y me interesa obtener en un nuevo array solo los elementos que cumplan esa condición y pasar esos valores a `Double`.
El código es:

```java
for(int i=0;i<cadenaValores.length;i++){
   if(cadenaValores[i].matches("[0-9]{0,5}")){
       System.out.println(cadenaValores[i]);   
   }
}
```

Me saca por pantalla los elementos que me interesan pero estoy atascada, no sé cómo sacar cada uno por separado y pasarlos a `Double`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Si queres usar un array para guardar los valores que cumplan con la condición,primero debes saber cuando numeros cumplen esa condición para declarar el tamaño que tendrá el arreglo double
ejemplo:

```
//usamos la varible cont para saber cuantos numeros cumplen la condicion

String[]cadenaValores={"3405","7856326","a54655","12345","145.56"};

int cont=0;
for(int i=0;i<cadenaValores.length;i++){
   if(cadenaValores[i].matches("[0-9]{0,5}")){
       cont++;  
   }
}
//con la cantidad obtenida declaramos el nuevo array y realizamos el cast de String a double
double[]valoresD=new double[cont];
int indiceD=0;
for(int i=0;i<cadenaValores.length;i++){
   if(cadenaValores[i].matches("[0-9]{0,5}")){
        valoresD[indiceD]=Double.parseDouble(cadenaValores[i]);
        indiceD++; 
   }
}
```

todo esto puede ser resumido usando java 8 expresiones lambda ,con el que obtendrias los mismo resultados

```
double[]valoresD2=Arrays.stream(cadenaValores).filter(i->i.matches("[0-9]{0,5}"))
                            .mapToDouble(num->Double.parseDouble(num)).toArray();
```

ten presente que usando una lista no seria necesario saber la cantidad de numeros que cumplen la condicion simplemente podemos agregar pero una lista no aplica a tipo de datos primitivos

Answer (score 0):

Espero que esto te  sirva.

```
import java.util.*;

public class Main {
    public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
        // Your code here!
        ArrayList<Double> lista=new ArrayList<Double>();
        ArrayList<Double> listaPares=new ArrayList<Double>();
        Double numero;
        for(int i=0;i<5;i++){
            numero=new Double(i);
            lista.add(numero);
   if(lista.get(i)%2==0){
       System.out.println(lista.get(i));
      numero=Double.valueOf(lista.get(i));
       listaPares.add(numero);
   }
}
for(int e=0;e<listaPares.size();e++){
     System.out.println(lista.get(e));
    }
}
}
```

Comment: Tal y como está redactada, tu respuesta no es clara. Por favor, pulsa en [edit] para añadir detalles adicionales que ayuden a los demás a entender cómo esto responde a la pregunta formulada. Puedes encontrar más información sobre cómo escribir buenas respuestas [en el centro de ayuda](/help/how-to-answer).

Comment: Era innecesario que elimines lo que mencionaste en tu edición anterior, ya que explica qué es lo que se tiene que hacer. No olvides editar tu respuesta y explicar tu código.

Answer (score 0):

Solución cavernícola.

```
 String[] cadenaValores = { "3405", "7856326", "a54655", "12345", "145.56" };      
 String aux = "";
 for( String in : cadenaValores ) {
     if( in.matches( "[0-9]{0,5}" ) ) {
        aux += in + ",";
     }   
  }
  
  String aux2[] = aux.split( "," );
  double salida[] = new double[ aux2.length ];

  for( int i = 0; i < aux2.length; i++ ) {
     salida[ i ] = Double.parseDouble( aux2[ i ] );
  }
```

El funcionamiento es sencillo, se recorre el array, cuando se haya una coincidencia con el patrón, se añade a la variable "aux", el valor contenido en el array más una coma (a fin de poder separar los términos).
Luego creamos un nuevo array a partir de la cadena recién creada, y otro array de doubles de igual longitud.
El segundo for, simplemente parsea el valor contenido en "aux" y lo guarda en salida.

PD: esta es una solución para los que están a mi nivel de entendimiento, **la respuesta de @Dramaturgo es mucho mejor**.